# Group by optional columns using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, group-by

I´ve got an xml like this:

```
<LiftFactors>
  <Products>
     <Product>
       <ProductId>Limella</ProductId>
       <Tactics>
         <Tactic>
           <Typ>PriceRed</Typ>
           <TPRFrom>0</TPRFrom>
           <TprThru>10</TprThru>
           <Lift>14</Lift>
           <VF>2012-01-09</VF>
           <VT>2012-01-11</VT>
        </Tactic>
        <Tactic>
           <Typ>PriceRed</Typ>
           <TPRFrom>10 </TPRFrom>
           <TprThru>20</TprThru>
           <Lift>30</Lift>
           <VF>2012-01-07</VF>
           <VT>2012-20-08</VT>
        </Tactic>
        <Tactic>
            <Typ>Display</Typ>
            <Lift>14</Lift> 
            <VF>2012-01-04</VF>
            <VT>2012-01-06</VT>
        </Tactic>
      </Tactics>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductId>Empower Cola</ProductId>
        <Tactics>
           <Tactic>
               <Typ>Display</Typ>
               <Lift>20</Lift>
               <VF>2012-01-01</VF>
               <VT>2012-01-08</VT>
           </Tactic>
        </Tactics>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</LiftFactors>
```

With the following linq statement I´m getting the Tactic data grouped by the ProductId and ordered by the ValidFrom date:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(theXML);
var d =  (from e in xml.Descendants(@"Product")
          group e by e.Element("ProductId").Value into Items
         select Items).ToDictionary 
         (x => x.Key, x => ((XElement)x.First()).Descendants("Tactic").ToList().OrderByDescending (y=> ((DateTime)y.Element("VF"))));
```

Output:

```
  Limella -> Tactic PriceRed 1
          -> Tactic PriceRed 2
          -> Tactic Display
  Empower Cola -> Tactic Display
```

Now assume the 'Product' nodes are optional and I can have additionally Tactic nodes outside the Product nodes:

```
<LiftFactors>
  <Products>
     <Product>
       <ProductId>Limella</ProductId>
       <Tactics>
         <Tactic>
           <Typ>PriceRed</Typ>
           <TPRFrom>0</TPRFrom>
           <TprThru>10</TprThru>
           <Lift>14</Lift>
           <VF>2012-01-09</VF>
           <VT>2012-01-11</VT>
        </Tactic>
       </Tactics>
     </Product>
   </Products>
   <Tactics>
         <Tactic>
           <Typ>PriceRed</Typ>
           <TPRFrom>0</TPRFrom>
           <TprThru>10</TprThru>
           <Lift>14</Lift>
           <VF>2012-01-09</VF>
           <VT>2012-01-11</VT>
         </Tactic>
   </Tactics>
</LiftFactors>
```

Now what I want is this output:

```
Limella -> Tactic 1
        -> ...
<Null>  -> Tactic 2
        -> ....
```

So the tactics should also appear in the group having no key assigned. Is this possible with only one linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d = xml.Descendants("Tactics")
           .GroupBy(e=>e.Parent.Name.LocalName == "Product" ?
                       e.Parent.Element("ProductId").Value : "")
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => ((XElement)x.First())
                                     .Descendants("Tactic").ToList()
                                     .OrderByDescending (y=>(DateTime)y.Element("VF")));
```

**NOTE**: The group having `Tactics` outside `Product` has key as `empty string`, you can change the code a little (by using If-else) to change it to `null`.

Comment: Thank you! Working very well.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work with your example XML, this gives you an enumarable collection of anonymous objects, the id field of these objects is populated if **Tactic** is inside a **Product**, null otherwise:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(contents);

var d = xml.Descendants("Tactic").Select(element => element.Parent != null ? new
    {
        id = element.Parent.Parent.Element("ProductId"),
        Tactic = new
            {
                Typ = element.Descendants("Typ").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                TPRFrom = element.Descendants("TPRFrom").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                TprThru = element.Descendants("TprThru").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                VF = element.Descendants("VF").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                VT = element.Descendants("VT").FirstOrDefault().Value
            }
    } : null);
```

Comment: That doesn't work with the XML the OP showed. Your code still assumes that the tactics are inside a `Product` tag which they aren't

Comment: Thanks for your effort JMK. But unfortunately it doesn´t work like Daniel already said.